# Using the media controls on my earbuds

Tags: volume-control, media, audio-jack

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 18.08 and I use my Samsung earbuds as headphone for it, now the laptop definitely has a 4-pin jack as I can use the microphone, but I can't seem to find any documentation or software for using the media buttons, they work on Windows out of the box, but not on Ubuntu it seems.

Where should I be looking for something like this? I assume there's some software capable of mapping these buttons to media or similar.